# Wrong table header border in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I would like to know, if this is a bug. As you can see on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyARs/), there is only top border instead of borders around all cells. Note that IE 9 draws borders as expected. Also note that if you move the content of `<tfooter>` in the `<tbody>`, Firefox starts drawing borders as IE.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <span class="norecords">No records found.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tfoot>
<tbody></tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    border-collapse: collapse;
} 
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
}
```

Comment: i use chrome and the border works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `tbody` - if you remove this empty tag (or add a row to it) it will work :

http://jsfiddle.net/FyARs/3/

Comment: Aaaa, you are right. Is this part of the html specification or something?

Comment: I just think different browsers handle empty tags in tables differently - ie used to have problems with empty cells (not sure if it still does!)

Comment: Anyway, it's weird. I don't understand why empty body would affect left and right borders of the header cells.

Comment: [This is a better source of information about the tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) - I think in your case the `tfoot` should be a `tbody` as your table doesn't really have any footer information - the only reason to put tfoot before tbody is to load the footer info before it loads any long table

Answer (score 0):

This works for all

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <span class="norecords">No records found.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </tfoot>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
}
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It because the different ways browsers dealing with collapse borders.

In firefox, an empty `tbody` without `tr` in it, it will be treated as no-border, the no-border edge will over the edge of nearly rows.

just remove unused `tbody` in your case, or put at least a pair of `<tr></tr>` in it.

Comment: I'm following the w3schools recommendation. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp, namely "The <tfoot> tag must be used in the following context: As a child of a <table> element, after any <caption>, <colgroup>, and <thead> elements and before any <tbody> and <tr> elements."